# importing LWJGL source

Tags: intellij-idea, import, lwjgl, javadoc

I have imported the compiled jars for lwjgl, but how do I import the source for them so I may view the source if I please? Also, how would I import the javadoc for it?

This was simple in Netbeans, but in Intellij I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the library configuration you can attach files or directories and specify JavaDoc URL:

[image: add]

Related documentation:

- [Configuring Module Dependencies and Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html)
- [Configuring Project and Global Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-project-and-global-libraries.html)